# Applying CollectionDifference to NSTableView

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

For this example lets assume I generate a `CollectionDifference` from ann `Int` array, and then calling `inferringMoves` on it like this

```swift
let a = [18, 18, 19, 11]
let b = [11, 19]
let diff = b.difference(from: a).inferringMoves()

for change in diff {
    switch change {
    case let .insert(offset, _, associatedWith):
        if let from = associatedWith {
            print("MOVE", from, offset)
        } else {
            print("INSERT", offset)
        }
    case let .remove(offset, _, associatedWith):
        // If it is a MOVE it was already recorded in .insert
        if associatedWith == nil {
            print("REMOVE", offset)
        }
    }
}
```

Now I need to take the changes array and feed it to `NSTableViews` update methods

- `insertRows`
- `removeRows`
- `moveRow`

in such a way, that it applies cleanly. My problem here is the offsets for `move` entries. The snippet above produces:

```
REMOVE 1
REMOVE 0
MOVE 2 1
```

Now obviously I cannot call `removeRows` for `0` and `1`, and then `moveRow(2, 1)`, but that is what the diff suggests.

How can I apply this cleanly?

The problem seems to be that `NSTableView` immediately updates its internal counts when applying an insert/delete, so a move won't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short Answer:**

`inferringMoves()` doesn't do what you think it does. Take a careful look at the result, in particular the value of `associatedWith`, and develop an algorithm which actually produces the removes, inserts and *moves* you need – `inferringMoves()` doesn't actually produce any moves...

**Long Answer:**

Your question intrigued me as I'd never looked at `CollectionDifference` before, so I'd get to look at it. First step do some searching on the Internet, this turns up Apple's documentation (poor as usual, it is written for those who already know the semantics, why can't they supply decent documentation anymore – most of the decent stuff is in their "archive", but I diverge...) and a number of sites describing the feature and including sample code. A fair bit of that sample code is different than yours, don't feel bad though as it doesn't work either.

Why that long ramble? Well finding no working code makes one wonder whether you're suffering from "lockdown fever" and your brain is addled. Does all the code really not work? Well it works for some data sets but not in the general case, Apple calling the beast `inferringMoves` is a bit of a bum steer, it infers the pairs of remove & insert operations in the sequence which together have the effect of moving an item but it doesn't actually infer the single move operation.

Or so my possibly (more than usual) addled brain says. Read on and decided whether I have lockdown fever or not...

Let's look at your data and see what `difference` produces and how each step changes the input:

```
Input: [18, 18, 19, 11]

Sequence of changes from `difference` and the changing sequence:
    remove(offset: 2, element: 19, associatedWith: -) => [18, 18, 11]
    remove(offset: 1, element: 18, associatedWith: -) => [18, 11]
    remove(offset: 0, element: 18, associatedWith: -) => [11]
    insert(offset: 1, element: 19, associatedWith: -) => [11, 19] CORRECT
```

What is important in this sequence is that the `offset` at any step takes account of all the previous steps, that is it is an offset into the intermediate result.

Now `inferringMoves` sets the `associatedWith` field to indicate `remove/insert` pairs which form a move, applying this to the `difference` of your data produces:

```
remove(offset: 2, element: 19, associatedWith: 1)
remove(offset: 1, element: 18, associatedWith: -)
remove(offset: 0, element: 18, associatedWith: -)
insert(offset: 1, element: 19, associatedWith: 2)
```

So the first and last actions are inferred as a move pair.

You decided, and you are not alone in that decision, that the insert action was the when the move should be performed, let's see what happens:

```
[18, 18, 19, 11]
remove(offset: 2, element: 19, associatedWith: 1) => [18, 18, 19, 11]
    Noop as part of a move pair
remove(offset: 1, element: 18, associatedWith: -) => [18, 19, 11]
    Item 1 was 18 so this seems valid...
remove(offset: 0, element: 18, associatedWith: -) => [19, 11]
    Item 0 is not 18 so this looks like things are going wrong
insert(offset: 1, element: 19, associatedWith: 2) => Oops
    Second action of a move pair, Error item 1 is not 19 and there is no item 2
```

As you found at that doesn't work. Others on the internet decided that it is remove action that is the move, do they fare any better?

```
[18, 18, 19, 11]
remove(offset: 2, element: 19, associatedWith: 1) => [18, 19, 18, 11]
    First of pair, do the move
remove(offset: 1, element: 18, associatedWith: -) => [18, 18, 11]
    Warning bell the item removed is 19 not 18 as the action expects
remove(offset: 0, element: 18, associatedWith: -) => [18, 11]
    Yah, item 0 is 18, this action is "correct" in isolation
insert(offset: 1, element: 19, associatedWith: 2) => [18, 11]
    Second of pair, so NOOP
```

That doesn't work either, so don't feel bad that yours didn't as I've yet to find any code on the internet that does work (that's not to say there isn't any out there), getting this wrong is common probably in part due to many simple examples working by chance.

The key to solving the problem is figuring out (as Apple don't make it clear) that the `associatedWith` value is the index that will be (for a future insert) or was (for a past remove) the effected index in the sequence as it exists/existed *at the time* the associated action takes/took place.

E.g. the first action for your data is `remove(offset: 2, element: 19, associatedWith: 1)`, that doesn't mean that you can move the item to index 1 in the *current* sequence but to index 1 in the sequence as it will exist when the associated `insert(offset: 1, element: 19, associatedWith: 2)` is performed. There are two intervening remove actions between the remove & inset of the pair so the sequence will be changing.

To get to a (*not the only*) working solution you can post process the result of `inferringMoves()` with the following sketched algorithm:

1. Delete any remove operation with an `associatedWith` value and adjust the `offset` values in all following operations allowing for the element that was to be removed being still in the sequence; and
2. Adjust the `associatedWith` value to be the current offset of the element that was not removed by the paired remove operation that was deleted.

This will produce a sequence of zero or more remove and insert actions without `associatedWith` values, and one or more insert actions with `associatedWith` values which represent moves.

Applying an implementation of the above algorithm sketch to your data produces:

```
[18, 18, 19, 11]
remove(offset: 1, element: 18, associatedWith: -) => [18, 19, 11]
remove(offset: 0, element: 18, associatedWith: -) => [19, 11]
insert(offset: 2, element: 19, associatedWith: 0) => [11, 19]
    a move: insert at offset, remove at associatedWith
```

Implementing this or another algorithm is, as is the SO way not being a code writing service, left to you. Hopefully the above explanation makes sense! If you get stuck with your implementation you can ask a new question, describing your algorithm, showing your code, and describing the problem your are facing; someone will undoubtedly help you take the next step.

**Disclaimer:**

As indicated at the start I was rather surprised to find no working code on the internet but quite a few broken ones, is my lockdown brain too addled? Is there a simple interpretation of the result of `inferringMoves()` which does not require the mixup step described above? It feels like there should be, Apple's documentation may be poor but the semantics of their APIs is usually good. So maybe, and if so I hope someone posts it as answer at which time I'll delete this one even though it does work.

Comment: The thing is Apple originally designed CollectionDifferece exactly for this kind of thing, so it seemed weird to me that I couldn't apply it more or less directly. I came to the same conclusion that I'd need postprocessing to make it work, but for now I am just not inferring moves. Thanks for the detailed answer, maybe sometime I'll get around to implementing postprocessing.

Answer (score 5):

So this was significantly more complicated than I initially thought!

Here is an extension on CollectionDifference that will return a set of steps that includes moves. I have tested this on varied and complicated sequences and it seems solid.

EDIT:
I re-wrote the below code to remove a few edge failures, with the much appreciated help of a test suite created by @paxos. A Swift Package with the solution is here: https://github.com/GilesHammond/DifferenceTracker

```
/*
 This extension generates an array of steps that can be applied sequentially to an interface, or
 associated collection, to remove, insert AND move items. Apart from the first and last steps, all
 step indexes are transient and do not relate directly to the start or end collections.
 
 The standard Changes are ordered: removals high->low, insertions low->high. RemainingRemovalTracker
 is used to track the position of items left in the collection, but that are assumed absent in the
 offsets provided for later insertions.
 */

typealias RemainingRemovalTracker = [Int:Int]

extension RemainingRemovalTracker {
    
    mutating func addSkippedRemoval(atOffset offset: Int) {
        self[offset] = offset }
    
    mutating func useSkippedRemoval(withOriginalOffset originalOffset: Int) -> Int {
        let currentOffset = removeValue(forKey: originalOffset)!
        removalMade(at: currentOffset)
        return currentOffset }
    
    mutating func removalMade(at offset: Int) {
        forEach({ key, value in
            if value > offset {
                self[key] = value - 1 } })
    }
    
    mutating func insertionMade(at offset: Int) {
        forEach { key, value in
            if value >= offset {
                self[key] = value + 1 } }
    }

    func adjustedInsertion(withOriginalOffset originalOffset: Int) -> Int {
        var adjustedOffset = originalOffset

        values.sorted().forEach { offset in
            if offset <= adjustedOffset {
                adjustedOffset += 1 } }
        
        return adjustedOffset
    }
}

extension CollectionDifference where ChangeElement: Hashable
{
    public typealias Steps = Array<CollectionDifference<ChangeElement>.ChangeStep>
    
    public enum ChangeStep {
        case insert(_ element: ChangeElement, at: Int)
        case remove(_ element: ChangeElement, at: Int)
        case move(_ element: ChangeElement, from: Int, to: Int)
    }
    
    var maxOffset: Int { Swift.max(removals.last?.offset ?? 0, insertions.last?.offset ?? 0) }
    
    public var steps: Steps {
        guard !isEmpty else { return [] }
        
        var steps = Steps()
        var offsetTracker = RemainingRemovalTracker()

        inferringMoves().forEach { change in
            switch change {
            case let .remove(offset, element, associatedWith):
                if associatedWith != nil {
                    offsetTracker.addSkippedRemoval(atOffset: offset)
                } else {
                    steps.append(.remove(element, at: offset))
                    offsetTracker.removalMade(at: offset)
                }

            case let.insert(offset, element, associatedWith):
                if let associatedWith = associatedWith {
                    let from = offsetTracker.useSkippedRemoval(withOriginalOffset: associatedWith)
                    let to = offsetTracker.adjustedInsertion(withOriginalOffset: offset)
                    steps.append(.move(element, from: from, to: to))
                    offsetTracker.insertionMade(at: to)
                } else {
                    let to = offsetTracker.adjustedInsertion(withOriginalOffset: offset)
                    steps.append(.insert(element, at: to))
                    offsetTracker.insertionMade(at: to)
                }
            }
        }

        return steps
    }
}

extension CollectionDifference.Change
{
    var offset: Int {
        switch self {
        case let .insert(offset, _, _): return offset
        case let .remove(offset, _, _): return offset
        }
    }
}
```

These steps can be applied to an NSTableView or NSOutlineView like so:

```
for step in updates {
    switch step {
    case let .remove(_, index):
        outlineView.removeItems(at: [index], inParent: node, withAnimation: animation)
                    
    case let .insert(element, index):
        outlineView.insertItems(at: [index], inParent: node, withAnimation: animation)

    case let .move(element, from, to):
        outlineView.moveItem(at: from, inParent: node, to: to, inParent: node)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing! This seems to be one of the only fully working implementations I have seen so far!

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work (any longer?) - the test suite is also named NSOutlineViewPatchTestSuite, but only tests an NSTableView. The indexes passed through here would need to be relative to the parent, which can be worked out pretty simply, but it's still a bit misleading that this is a complete solution.

Comment: @TonyArnold This was only ever intended as a light solution to the question. I use it on NSOutlineView since its remove/insert/move interface is per parent node. Please let me know how it did not work for you?

Comment: @Giles there's no affordance here for the from/to parent nodes in any of the outline view methods. I get it: "exercise left up to the reader", but it's a big missing component.

Comment: @TonyArnold Ah, I see what you mean. My nodes have a list of children, and I simply apply child changes on a per node basis. You are correct that this only applies changes from a flat collection. You implied that it was broken - did you mean conceptually or technically?!

Comment: Conceptually, if you're using `NSOutlineView` as the example. I apologise, it's a perfectly fine answer if you're dealing with an `NSTableView`.